# selenium Opens the link in app prompt hiding python

Tags: python, selenium, discord

**I want to hide this message in selenium python**
it appears when i click on continue to discord
after doing :
`driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div/button').click()`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAFQz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it is alert.

to accept it in java

```
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

to cancel it

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

refer : https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/alerts/

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can try to dismiss the alert.

```py
driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
```

Or else you can use a keystroke using [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) module.
You need to install the pynput module first. Then,

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```